# Remote restart a Windows PC via Chromebook?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, vnc, reboot, remote-access

So my situation is a little bit weird. I have a Desktop PC at home (Windows 10 64) and a ChromeBook for school (provided by my school) I have a VNC server set up at home that allows me to remotely connect to it from school on my chromebook, which is convenient for Photoshop, AE, etc. Sometimes my server crashes, or starts lagging really bad, and I want a way to be able to remotely restart it from a chromebook so I can get it back up and running without having to go home. If it isn't possible, can I do it with an iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Chrome RDP](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-rdp/cbkkbcmdlboombapidmoeolnmdacpkch) in Chrome Web Store for your Chromebook to remote access your windows PC

**OR**

Download [iDisplay](http://getidisplay.com/) to your iPhone and to your Windows PC to Remote access your desktop

Comment: Is there possibly a free alternative to Chrome RDP? Also, it seems a bit overkill. I might try it, but I'm looking for a small gadget that allows me to simply remotely restart. See, I prefer to use RealVNC because it works best for me, and using both RealVNC and ChromeRDP will probably lag, since they are both remote desktop services.

Comment: @JoshSilveous Actually there are several Web Applications out there in Chrome web store and I really need to know your requirements to use it. Otherwise it is simple as it is.

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by requirements.. What I'm looking for is a simple interface that has a button that allows me to remotely trigger a restart on my computer. A remote Command Prompt would do aswell.

Comment: if possible check out if "windows remote desktop" is there for chromebook, but that gets lagging. So the best is to use iDisplay from your iPhone